# Can I apply for spousal visa ? I have been refused under 320 7(a)

Tags: visas, uk, spouses

I am married to a girl in the UK. We are now planing to apply for a spousal visa. I was refused under 320 7(a) in 2009 due to false bank statement submission. Will this automatic ban period affect this new visa application as it is a spousal visa and I was refused a student visa? Please help me find a way out if any.[image]

Comment: Can you upload the refusal notice with personal information blacked out?

Comment: Let's find out. The main reason I want to see it is if the OP actually has a ban, or if it's the usual "If you apply again in the next ten years you may be banned" response.

Comment: Dear all. Please see the attachement

Comment: @S.f.t Is there another page? The portion you attached doesn't mention false bank accounts.

Comment: Zach lipton please see tge attached pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were refused under 320 (7A) for providing a false document (bank statement) and, for that reason, under 245ZV(c), that you did not have sufficient funds to be a genuine student.

However, the encouraging bit is the exception, making application for a [family visa, as a partner or spouse](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse) which does not attract the ban:

> [**Immigration Rules part 9: grounds for refusal**](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal)
>
> A320. Paragraphs 320 (except subparagraph (3), (10) and (11)) and 322 do not apply to an application for entry clearance, leave to enter or leave to remain as a Family Member under Appendix FM, and Part 9 (except for paragraph 322(1)) does not apply to an application for leave to remain on the grounds of private life under paragraphs 276ADE-276DH.

Should you need guidance, you might want input from an immigration advisor, which you can find through the [Immigration Law Practitioners' Association](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/pages/find-immigration-advice.html).

Comment: thanks for you guidence. Can yiu please guide me about the best solicitor or immigration lawyer around Birmingham or coventry region.

Comment: @S.f.t sorry, no, TSE offers direct answers to questions, not such advice which is subject to opinion. Just go to the [ILPA search engine](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/search-directory.php) and select West Midlands, and it will return a slew of options.